# What kind of service panel to use when the enemy is condensate, not rain?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have looked  at indoor and outdoor panels.  However, the design of the outdoor panel seems to be geared to excluding rain, falling from top to bottom or a little sideways.  Actually, my location can't have rain, but it does have issues with condensation.

What special characteristics should I look for in such a panel?

Comment: Are you stuck with loadcenter-type hardware here, or can you go to a specification panelboard? (Eaton PRL1, Square-D NQ, Siemens P1)?  Also, what all needs to be served from this?

Comment: Yeah, I am game to those.  Small dimensional size is a priority though.

Comment: Does that 'small dimensional size' requirement include having to be 14" wide or narrower?  Also, does this panel need to have a main breaker in it, how many circuits are you trying to feed here, and what overall amp rating are you looking at?

Comment: I'm looking at no more than 40A for the panel.  It will switch a variety of lights and possibly some heaters, probably 12 spaces worth of circuits but segregated by lighting area more than load.  I can live with 14" wide but would prefer narrower.

Comment: How severe of a condensing condition are we talking about? Is it something that a breather vent could deal with, or would we need to take more extreme measures?  What is the source of this humidity/condensation?

Comment: No, it's pretty bad.  I have found the surface covered in dew droplets. I was afraid to operate a breaker.

Comment: It sounds like this may be beyond what a passive solution can achieve -- is having a dehumidifier or heater in the box an option?

Comment: I have used small fire rod heaters in the past where this was a problem, they run off of 120v and are designed for a gun safe. I don’t know if they make them small enough to fit in that small of a panel but the little warmth they generate keeps the panel from condensation issues.

Comment: Write that up as an answer @EdBeal so I can upvote it... Tha won't help here, but will solve a problem at another site... I can find heaters that small, and To get a low enough wattage I can run 240V or 480V ones on 120...

Comment: I do that same thing at my plant for some of the equipment panels it really helps extend the panel life in a nasty environment+ I do verify I can hold on to them but get the long 1/2” ones (I don’t know if I would do that at a customer site I figure the UL listing covers for those cases)

Comment: @Harper -- I take it you're saying that a dehumidifier wouldn't be an option, either, when you're rejecting using a heater to keep the air in the box above its dewpoint?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Right, because the box is often totally unpowered.

Comment: 3 phase I am not sure I follow , these do keep the box above the dew point I think they are usually only 20w or so very warm to the touch but not hot enough to burn.

Comment: @EdBeal -- the lack of an always-hot power supply is what's ruling out an active (heater or dehumidifier) approach to this problem

Comment: i Have put these in California, Oregon, Ohio, Indiana Washington, it is simple physics , heat the box above the dew point and it works. If you have a better way I would love to hear it!

Comment: @EdBeal -- the other active option I was referring to was that Hoffman and others make small dehumidifiers intended to go into electrical cabinets (control panels and such are where they're most commonly found).  The heater approach is workable in most cases though as well, and probably a trifle more reliable too.  (AIUI, there are also heaters specifically designed for what you are doing)

Answer (score 4):

As requested: 
I have used small fire rod heaters in the past where condensation was a problem, 
they run off of 120v and are designed for a gun safe. 
I don’t know if they make them small enough to fit in a 40 amp panel. the little warmth they generate keeps the panel from condensation issues. I have done this in pool areas and open metal buildings. 
The first time I did this I asked the inspector, since then I have been asked what they were and after explaining have always been approved on inspection.

Answer (score 1):

When a panel is rated for "Outdoor Use", often called "Type 3R" or "Raintight", that does not ONLY mean it will not allow falling rain to enter, it ALSO means that no liquid will build up inside to any live electrical parts. So they must also have a "weep hole" of some sort that allows any liquid, including condensate, to drain out safely.

Comment: Yeah, the issue seems to be that humid air is getting into the existing box and condensing *directly onto live parts*, though.

Comment: The 3r works ok but if the panel is cold and there is fog the fog condenses inside as well as outside. The only way to prevent this I have found is to warm the panel so it won’t condense moisture , started doing this on swimming pool and barn panels in the early 80’s. I did ask an inspector and he ok’ed the idea and have done it ever since where moisture could be a problem , have not failed an inspection with them in and have been asked many times what they are.

Comment: I have used a small surface mount lamp socket and a 40W refrigerator bulb as an anti-condensation heater on small panels.

Comment: @JRaef Just wait...in a few years you'll start getting calls because someone replaced the incandescent bulb when it burned out with a 3W LED bulb that doesn't generate enough heat! For that matter, I'll bet there are people out there trying to use their old EZ-Bake ovens from 30 years ago with their grandchildren after replacing the old light bulb and wondering why they don't seem to bake as well as they used to!

Comment: Type 3R, *minimum*, +1 (to provide a degree of protection with respect to harmful effects on the equipment due to the ingress of water (rain, sleet, snow); that provides an additional level of protection against corrosion).

Comment: Type 6 if you're worried: (hose directed water and the entry of water during occasional temporary submersion at a limited depth).

Comment: And Type 6P if you're crazy: (hose directed water and the entry of water during prolonged submersion at a limited depth); that provides an additional level of protection against corrosion and that will be undamaged by the external formation of ice 
on the enclosure.

Comment: [PDF - NEMA Enclosure Types](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=2ahUKEwj3hJvDwdTlAhV85-AKHQf1Dr0QFjAKegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nema.org%2Fproducts%2Fdocuments%2Fnema-enclosure-types.pdf&usg=AOvVaw11OOFPwdy1rvt7FUUzDxJl)